# Pandas skiprows[1] is not working as expected?

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to read my csv using pandas library.
My csv is like;

```
 Tank Export for Wednesday 28/08/2019 at 12:00 p.m.,,,,,,,
    Site,Tank ID,Product,Volume,Water Level,Temperature,Ullage,Dip Time
    aaaa,bb,cc,....
    .....
```

Im trying to read this csv liek;

```
date_col = ['Dip Time']
 if (f.endswith('.CSV')):
            data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(atg_path, f), delimiter=',',
                               dayfirst=True, skiprows=[1],
                               parse_dates=date_col)
```

Here i expect pandas will skip first row(starting as **"Tank export for**") which is not needed for processing.
But I get;

```
ValueError: 'Dip Time' is not in list
```

Why is that? Can't I skip a row and make pandas to read and process rest of the lines in a CSV/excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the square brackets from `skiprows=[1]` and your code will work correctly. Do this:

```
data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(atg_path, f), delimiter=',',
                               dayfirst=True, skiprows=1,
                               parse_dates=date_col)
```

**Note**: [skiprows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) accept as parameters list-like, int or callable. In your case you could also do `skiprows=[0]` which is equivalent to doing `skiprows=1`

Comment: can you  explain what is meant by [] and without it

Comment: skiprows=[1] means to skip the line 1, skiprows=[0] means to skip the line 0... skiprows= [0,1] means to skip the line 0 and line 1...

Comment: @RajithThennakoon No, skiprows in the latest versions accept as parameters: list-like, int or callable

Comment: @Ratha In your case you could also do skiprows=[0] which is equivalent to doing skiprows=1